# Starting Monitor Daemon for Secure Virtual Private Network: cp: cannot stat `/etc/inittab': No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

> when I was installing software using 
>   apt-get, the following error occurred:

```
Setting up secvpn (2.23) ... 
Starting Monitor Daemon for Secure Virtual Private Network: cp: cannot    stat `/etc/inittab': No such file or directory
invoke-rc.d: initscript secvpnmon, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing secvpn (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
secvpn
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please give us more details, states clearly your system with version (not only in the tag) and the software you are trying to install. See also how to ask good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: belongs to http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar error and helped me here is a simple solution:

```
sudo touch /etc/inittab
```